# Codificação em Blocos

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Estou tentando desenvolver uma aplicação de [*Codificação em Blocos*](http://code.org/api/hour/begin/codeorg). Encontrei dificuldades para desenvolver este tipo de aplicação.

Com os eventos abaixo, consigo identificar quando há uma colisão entre outros controles e arrastar os controles. Porém, não consegui identificar quando "saio" da colisão e quando eu solto o controle que estou arrastando em cima de outro, neste caso, ele deveria se reposicionar de uma forma que identifique a árvore de controles. No final, vou criar um código baseado nos controles adicionados.

Estou fazendo da maneira correta? Existe alguma outra ferramenta mais simples de desenvolver aplicações deste tipo?

## MouseDown Event

```
     private void DynamicButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

                if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
                MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }
```

## MouseMove Event

```
     private void DynamicButton_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                Button btn = (Button)sender;

            foreach (Control item in Controls)
            {
                if (btn.Bounds.IntersectsWith(item.Bounds) && (item.Name != btn.Name))
                {
                    item.BackColor = Color.Yellow;



                }
            }


                if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
                {

                    btn.Left = e.X + btn.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
                    btn.Top = e.Y + btn.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Você está desenvolvendo em Windows Forms ? Você está desenvolvendo isso do zero, ou seja todas as iterações gráficas é você está fazendo ? Não seria mais interessante pegar um componente pronto ?